# Django Admin raise 500 error in production Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-admin

I know this question was raised multiple times, but wasn't able to solve the problem.
Here is my problem: my Django-React app is deployed on Heroku and works great (very simple app). I would like know to access the /admin part of my app, but I get a 500 Internal Server Error.
The error appears locally and in Heroku.
The DEBUG is False, and unfortunately I can't get the logs to work, neither in Heroku nor locally :(

Here is my settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import django_heroku
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['vmbf.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost']


ADMINS = [('username', 'emailaddress')]
MANAGERS = ADMINSEMAIL_HOST = 'host'
SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS=True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'emailaddress'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',  
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'students',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',    
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_react_proj.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'students-fe/build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_react_proj.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
django_heroku.settings(locals())

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = (
    'https://vmbf.herokuapp.com',
)

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'vmbf.herokuapp.com',
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'students-fe', 'build', 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

And here is how my folder looks like:

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nowAW.png)

Feel free to ask me more code, I'm new to Django / React therefore I'm not sure what I should share here or not.

Comment: Did you run makemigrations and migrate command

Comment: Yes, and nothing to migrate `Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, students
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.`

Comment: Did you tried to run by setting ``DEBUG=True``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Django SQLite db from being overwritten while pushing to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738598/prevent-django-sqlite-db-from-being-overwritten-while-pushing-to-heroku)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to deploy Django with Sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35615273/354577)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: Deploying an application on Heroku with sqlite3 as the database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31395856/354577)

Comment: You can't use SQLite on Heroku. Please review the three duplicate links I just provided. Your best bet will be to migrate to a client-server data store like PostgreSQL.

Comment: So basically: Everything works on Heroku with `DEBUG=False` **but** the /admin part. Which works perfectly if I set `DEBUG=True` (again both on Heroku and locally). Do you really think it's related to SQLite vs PostgreSQL ?

Comment: @Chris I've installed PostgreSQL for testing, app still working (SQLite3 locally and PostgresSQL on Heroku), but still having the 500 Internal Server Error when trying to access /admin

Comment: I wouldn't recommend developing with SQLite and running production with Postgres. They're not drop-in replacements for each other and I've seen things break in production because of that. Suggest you switch to Postgres locally, too.

Comment: We'll need to see your logs to help. Please run [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs) and edit the output into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out my problem.

It was not related to PostgreSQL, but thank you @Chris to pointing that out, it's better development methodology for myself.

The problem was related to how I managed the Static Files in my settings.py

I didn't understood how STATIC_ROOT works, I understood the other way around. After reflecting on it here is what I did:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')
```

My files will be served from this **staticfiles** directories.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'students-fe','build','static'),
]
```

But it has to include my react app that is in students-fe/build/static folder.

On top of that, when deploying to Heroku, it is necessary to add the buildpacks, which I did but not in the correct order.

First I needed to add python (for Django):

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

and then saying that before that it needs to install nodejs (for React):

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

Like this Heroku will first do a **npm run build** before the **python manage.py collecstatic** that is needed to move the static files into the staticfiles folder.

Hope it can help others.
Thanks to all for your answers.